# How to open part of my page content into own broswer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if I have a page:

```
<body>
  <div id='part_one'>...</div>
  <div id='part_two'>...</div>
  <div id='part_three'>...</div>

  //Create a link here to open the content of div `part_two` in own browser
</body>
```

I would like to create a link on the page, when user click on the link, the content of div `part_two` will be opened in own browser, how to do it?

Comment: Would you prefer it be in a popup window instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="var w=window.open();w.document.write(document.getElementById('part_two').innerHTML);w.document.close();return false">Open #2 in new window</a>
```

This is a horribly crude way to make such a link, though. If the data must be opened in a new window, you always need to provide a fallback page (put that in `href`) and use unobtrusive JavaScript, so bind the `click` listener *in your script* and not like my example.